# How to start Docker daemon on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, daemon

On Windows, I've always been able to build Docker images with no problems.

I'm now trying to build a simple Docker image on Ubuntu 18.04 and typing in the terminal:

```
sudo docker build -t test .
```

results in the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. 
Is the docker daemon running?
```

How do I start the Docker daemon? I want to be able to build the image successfully

**EDIT:**

Typing `sudo systemctl start docker` as stated in the original documentation https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/ results in the following error:

```
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service is masked.
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

Comment: @leopal doing sudo systemctl start docker results in Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service is masked.

Comment: [Check this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393309)

Comment: Try running the following :  sudo systemctl unmask docker.service
sudo systemctl unmask docker.socket
sudo systemctl start docker.service

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can configure docker [to start on boot](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot) :

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

The ugly way : start docker manually :

```
dockerd &
```

Comment: dockerd & did the trick :D

Comment: Nice! Glad it worked.